# DocuSign API - Set "Mobile Friendly" option via API

Tags: docusignapi

We have some PDFs that don't work well with the default "Mobile Friendly" option when viewed on a smartphone. Is it possible to control this setting when sending an envelope via the DocuSign API?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`disableResponsiveDocument`](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopes/create/#schema__envelopedefinition_disableresponsivedocument) attribute to turn off responsive signing for the envelope.